# SEO: how to make articles more relevant? Or how to make overview pages less relevant?

Tags: seo, wordpress

I did a lot of Googling, but I did not seem to find something on the topic. According to [this thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281380/can-we-ask-seo-questions-on-stack-overflow) this question needs to be asked here.

I'm using a WordPress installation with a theme that renders the navigation as links. It also renders tags and categories as links. When I'm doing a Google search with "site:", I see that the navigation/overview pages are shown first (pages like date-pages, category-pages and tag-pages). Bing does a slightly better job, but still shows a lot of these overview pages.

**How can I make overview-pages less relevant to search engines like Google and Bing?**

Examples of [Google](https://www.google.nl/search?q=site%3Akeestalkstech.com) and [Bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Akeestalkstech.com):
[image: Google example for KeesTalksTech.com]
[image: Bing example for KeesTalksTech.com]

Comment: `site:example.com` in no way or form reflects on 'actual' your rankings. There is no way to bump pages when using such a search. You could force Google's hand by removing the tag pages from the index using 'noindex' on those pages, but be warned... pages that get links that are not indexed, do not pass link juice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend allowing only one of the archive ("overview") types to be indexed. They're all facet views of the same body of information, so a degree of duplication will occur and, inevitably, some will be more meaningful and useful as a user entry-point than others.

I'd suggest allowing categories to be indexed, and `noindex` the tag, date, and author archives, etc. Categories make the most sense from a UX and SEO point of view (i.e., people are likely to be searching for "articles about C#").

You can do this very easily with [Yoast's Wordpress SEO](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/).